# Vagrant is not booting up

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox

i am new here and have a problem with vagrant. I installed virtualbox and vagrant so I can use laravel-homestead. I have made everything according to the instruction in the article(https://tutsforweb.com/installing-laravel-homestead-on-windows-step-by-step/#1_Hardware_Virtualization). When i try to boot vagrant, i am geeting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        17: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/bin/vagrant:214:in `<main>'
        16: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/bin/vagrant:214:in `new'
        15: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:189:in `initialize'
        14: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:998:in `process_configured_plugins'
        13: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:817:in `vagrantfile'
        12: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:817:in `new'
        11: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:31:in `initialize'
        10: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `load'
         9: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `each'
         8: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `block in load'
         7: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `each'
         6: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in load'
         5: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.0/gems/vagrant-2.3.0/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
         4: from C:/Users/me/Homestead/Vagrantfile:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
         3: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:277:in `load'
         2: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:390:in `parse'
         1: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse_stream'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 6 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

Homestead.yamel

```
---
ip: "192.168.5.20"
memory: 8192
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox
​
authorize: c:/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
​
keys:
    - c:/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa
​
folders:
    - map: c:/workspace
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace
      type: nfs
​
sites:
    - map: code.test
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/code
      php: "8.1"
      
    - map: cmsmy-pro.dev.local
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/my-pro/public
      php: "7.2"
      type: cms-core
      
    - map: www.my-pro.com
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/my-pro/public/www
      php: "7.2"
      type: cms-core
      
    - map: cmsmy-pro.dev.local
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/cmsmy-pro/public
      php: "8.0"  
​
    - map: phpmyadmin.mysql
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/phpmyadmin
      php: "8.0"
​
databases:
    - homestead
​
features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
​
services:
    - enabled:
          - "mysql"
#    - disabled:
#        - "postgresql@11-main"
​
#ports:
#    - send: 33234 # MySQL/MariaDB
#      to: 2500
#    - send: 5020
#      to: 5020
#    - send: 58720 # PostgreSQL
#      to: 5473
#    - send: 2314 # Mailhog
#      to: 4723
#    - send: 2341
#      to: 2341
#    - send: 58711
#      to: 58711
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: there must be something wrong in your yaml file, please add it in the question

Comment: Hey i added the yaml file

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I copy your yaml, we can see there are [spaces](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) instead of empty lines

[image: revealed from editor]

following yaml should be ok

```yaml
---
ip: "192.168.5.20"
memory: 8192
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: c:/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - c:/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa


folders:
    - map: c:/workspace
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace
      type: nfs

sites:
    - map: code.test
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/code
      php: "8.1"
      
    - map: cmsmy-pro.dev.local
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/my-pro/public
      php: "7.2"
      type: cms-core
      
    - map: www.my-pro.com
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/my-pro/public/www
      php: "7.2"
      type: cms-core
      
    - map: cmsmy-pro.dev.local
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/cmsmy-pro/public
      php: "8.0"  

    - map: phpmyadmin.mysql
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/phpmyadmin
      php: "8.0"

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

services:
    - enabled:
          - "mysql"
#    - disabled:
#        - "postgresql@11-main"

#ports:
#    - send: 33234 # MySQL/MariaDB
#      to: 2500
#    - send: 5020
#      to: 5020
#    - send: 58720 # PostgreSQL
#      to: 5473
#    - send: 2314 # Mailhog
#      to: 4723
#    - send: 2341
#      to: 2341
#    - send: 58711
#      to: 58711
```

Comment: Vagrant is off topic. here. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Comment: @Rob General vagrant support is off topic, this question is not so much related to vagrant this issue was not vagrant but yaml from homestead) but to larval/homestead, its a programming question;